# Is there a way to track events of video embedded into a facebook wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, flash, video, tracking

My mission is to embed a video (custom player) into a facebook wall and track the users events (play count etc.), also gather other relevant data. I was wondering is this at all possible, if so, can you comment on that briefly?

TA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most tracking that I have seen in the past is done through Flash JavaScript communitcation using the ExternalInterface in the Flash API.

I can't comment on how this would be done in facebook, but you are essentially just sending out params (you decide what they are and when they are sent) and they come out in the page in a JS function and get handled there, either you pass them on to google analytics or do whatever after that.

[ExternalInterface on Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: That means I need my own custom player with ExternalInterface calls within swf. Or do other players (jw, kaltura) already have this provided as standard?

Comment: I guess you would need to have a look what their api provides, I know JW does use ExternalInterface but I don't know if it will suit your requirements, adding it in your own custom player is not a difficult taks to be honest. Check out Strobe Media Player also, that might be of use to you.